# I cannot perform a purchase function on a marketplace. I get execution reverted

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py, python, arbitrum

I'm trying to execute a purchase function in a marketplace and I can't, I get a return error and I can't understand how to resolve the error.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

# Initialize a web3 instance with an Infura node
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://arb1.arbitrum.io/rpc'))

# Address of the buyer (you)
buyer = '...'

# private key
private_key = '...'

# Address of the contract
contract_address = '0x1E3E1ed17A8Df57C215b45f00c2eC4717B33a93D'

# ABI of the contract
contract_abi = \[{
"constant": False,
"inputs": \[
{"name": "auctor\_", "type": "address"},
{"name": "index\_", "type": "uint256"},
{"name": "startTime\_", "type": "uint256"},
{"name": "price\_", "type": "uint256"},
{"name": "tradeType\_", "type": "uint256"}
\],
"name": "buy",
"outputs": \[\],
"type": "function"
}\]

# Create a contract instance
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

# Estimate the gas required for the transaction
gas_estimate = contract.functions.buy(
'0x4DD4daA34E912ff22204F4AEbF97f30c7C3Aaa79',  # Seller's address
0,  # index\_
1686615131,  # startTime\_
160000000,  # price\_
1  # tradeType\_
).estimate_gas()

# Construct a raw transaction
raw_tx = {
'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(buyer),
'gasPrice': web3.eth.gasPrice,
'gas': gas_estimate,
'to': contract_address,
'value': 0,
'data': contract.encodeABI(fn_name="buy", args=\['0x4DD4daA34E912ff22204F4AEbF97f30c7C3Aaa79', 0, 1686615131, 160000000, 1\])
}

# Sign the transaction
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(raw_tx, private_key)

# Send the transaction
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
print(f'Transaction hash: {tx_hash.hex()}')
```

In the code I already added the NFT information as an example, obviously when someone comes to help me, it may not be available and I would need to change it.

This is the error I get:
in raise_contract_logic_error_on_revert
raise ContractLogicError("execution reverted", data=data)
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted